# ¿Como mandar el XML a un web services mediante soap php?

Tags: php, xml, soap

buen día estoy haciendo una conexión a un servicio web mediante SOAP en PHPy me aconsejan mandar el XML para y cito 'se mas fácil'.

como seria mandar el XML por SOAP ya que no tiene activo el CURL ya que al intentar de enviar la información por CURL no se conecta.

cabe mencionar que en el arreglo no lo puedo mandar ya que solicitan que en un mismo nodo este repetido varias veces, ejemplo de como lo solicitan.

---

```
<RoomStay>
    <RPH>1</RPH>
        <GuestCounts>
            <GuestCount>
              <Count>1</Count><AgeQualifyingCode>10</AgeQualifyingCode><Age>30</Age>
            </GuestCount>
            <GuestCount>
                <Count>1</Count><AgeQualifyingCode>7</AgeQualifyingCode><Age>1</Age>
            </GuestCount>
            <GuestCount>
                <Count>1</Count><AgeQualifyingCode>8</AgeQualifyingCode><Age>21</Age>
            </GuestCount>
        </GuestCounts>
        <TimeSpan>
            <Start>2020-10-14</Start><End>2020-10-15</End>
        </TimeSpan>
        <RoomRates>
            <RoomRate>
                <RoomTypeCode>SGL</RoomTypeCode>
                <MealPlanCodes>SA</MealPlanCodes>
                <RatePlanCode>USD</RatePlanCode>
            </RoomRate>
        </RoomRates>
        <BasicPropertyInfo>
            <HotelCode>H01</HotelCode>
        </BasicPropertyInfo>
</RoomStay>
<RoomStay>
    <RPH>2</RPH>
    <GuestCounts>
        <GuestCount>
          <Count>3</Count><AgeQualifyingCode>10</AgeQualifyingCode><Age>30</Age>
        </GuestCount>
    </GuestCounts>
    <TimeSpan>
        <Start>2020-10-14</Start><End>2020-10-15</End>
    </TimeSpan>
    <RoomRates>
     <RoomRate>
        <RoomTypeCode>SGL</RoomTypeCode>
        <MealPlanCodes>AD</MealPlanCodes>
        <RatePlanCode>INTERNACIONAL</RatePlanCode>
     </RoomRate>
    </RoomRates>
    <BasicPropertyInfo>
        <HotelCode>H01</HotelCode>
    </BasicPropertyInfo>
</RoomStay>
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para los que les digan que manden XML
tendrán que hacer el XML de forma "manual" y luego usar el método.

simplexml_load_string($stringXML); para convertirlo en un array con clases.

luego usar json_encode para codificar ese array en un json.

de ultimo usar json_decode($jsoncodificado,true) el true sirve para hacer el json a un array asosiativo y mandelo asi al metodo que lo necesiten enviar la informacion.